How to explicitly set type to function in python
In python I can set the type of a parameter as
def example(param1: int):
  pass

and the return type as
def example() -> None:
  pass

however when I try to do this for classes I get an error
class Example:
  def __init__(self: Example) -> Example:
    pass

raises
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'Example' is not defined.

this also goes for functions that are not __init__ and for params that are not self
class Example:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def do_something(self, other_example_class: Example) -> None:
    pass

or even
class Example:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

class Example2:
  def __init__(self, data: Example):
    pass

Is it possible to explicitly set the type of a parameter to a class, including inside of the class definition?

@esqew because the error shows up outside of just self

To refer to the class itself before you finish defining it, put the class name in a string.
